# Play 2.1 Local Dev Mode complaining 'Cannot load ManualInjectionPlugin plugin'

Tags: playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

I got this error when upgrade to Play 2.1. 'play compile' is fine. However, I am not sure where this error comes from?

```
$ play ~run
[info] Loading project definition from ...

--- (Running the application from SBT, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0.0.0.0:9000

(Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)

......

! @6cin1d5no - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->

play.api.PlayException: Cannot load plugin[Plugin [com.typesafe.plugin.inject.ManualInjectionPlugin] cannot been instantiated.]
    at play.api.WithDefaultPlugins$$anonfun$plugins$1$$anonfun$apply$9.apply(Application.scala:146) ~[play_2.10-2.1-RC1.jar:2.1-RC1]
    at play.api.WithDefaultPlugins$$anonfun$plugins$1$$anonfun$apply$9.apply(Application.scala:124) ~[play_2.10-2.1-RC1.jar:2.1-RC1]
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:309) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.typesafe.plugin.inject.ManualInjectionPlugin
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202) ~[na:1.6.0_31]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_31]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190) ~[na:1.6.0_31]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306) ~[na:1.6.0_31]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247) ~[na:1.6.0_31]
    at play.api.WithDefaultPlugins$$anonfun$plugins$1$$anonfun$apply$9.apply(Application.scala:126) ~[play_2.10-2.1-RC1.jar:2.1-RC1]
```

This is the dependencies in Build.scala.

```
    val appDependencies = Seq(
       javaCore, javaJdbc, javaEbean,
       "com.github.twitter" % "bootstrap" % "2.0.4",
       "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901-1.jdbc4",
       "commons-codec" % "commons-codec" % "1.6",
@@ -18,7 +19,7 @@ object ApplicationBuild extends Build {
       ("com.jayway.facebooktestjavaapi" % "facebook-test-java-api" % "1.1.5" notTransitive()),
       "net.java.dev.jets3t" % "jets3t" % "0.9.0",
       "com.typesafe" % "play-plugins-inject" % "2.0.2",
       "com.typesafe" %% "play-plugins-mailer" % "2.1-SNAPSHOT",
       "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-testkit" % "2.0.2",
       "org.imgscalr" % "imgscalr-lib" % "4.2",
       "org.codehaus.jackson" % "jackson-jaxrs" % "1.9.5",
@@ -32,14 +33,10 @@ object ApplicationBuild extends Build {
       "com.sun.jersey" % "jersey-client" % "1.9-ea04",
       "com.sun.jersey" % "jersey-core" % "1.9-ea04",
       "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.0.0",
      "org.mindrot" % "jbcrypt" % "0.3m"
     )
```